# Selenium - Retaining firefox cache and history files

Tags: firefox, selenium

Is there a way to disable Selenium creating a temporary directory and profile when it starts Firefox?

I fully understand why Selenium does things as it does. I am just experimenting it as I try to create Firefox caches and histories with it for computer forensic training purposes.  To this end, I have set up a clean virtual machine with a pristine user account. I can now run a Python script with selenium API to start firefox, visit a couple of web pages and shut down.

THe problem is, it leaves nothing behind. This is of course excellent if you are using selenium in its original purpose, but it thwarts my work by deleting everything.

So is there a way to disable the temporary profile creation and just start Firefox as it would start if ran by the user without Selenium.

Addition 5:34PM:
Java API documentation mentions a system property webdriver.reap_profile that would prevent deletion of temporary files.  I went to the source of the problem and it appears this does not appear in Python WebDriver class:

```
def quit(self):
        """Quits the driver and close every associated window."""
        try:
            RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
        except (http_client.BadStatusLine, socket.error):
            # Happens if Firefox shutsdown before we've read the response from
            # the socket.
            pass
        self.binary.kill()
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(self.profile.path)
            if self.profile.tempfolder is not None:
                shutil.rmtree(self.profile.tempfolder)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Deletion of files upon quit appears to be unconditional.  I will solve this in my case by injecting

```
return self.profile.path
```

just after self.binary.kill().  This probably breaks all sorts of things and is a horrible thing to do but it appears to do exactly what I want it to do. The return value tells the calling function the random name of the temporary directory under /tmp.  Not elegant but appears to work.

Comment: Even if firefox is started normally, without selenium, it would use an existing profile directory, or would create one ([reference](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data)).

Comment: But when I start it normally, it creates ~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/xxxxx dir, xxxxx being the same in .mozilla/firefox. When started through Selenium, this directory does not appear.

This is my problem. Cache seems to be disabled or it appears in a temporary place and is deleted immediately.

Comment: Thanks, it is more clear now - you are talking about the cache, not profile. Gotcha.

Comment: Yes, sorry about the confusion.  

It appears to create /tmp/..hexid.../ dir containing both profile and cache information but this gets deleted as soon as I call quit().  If I do not quit firefox, the cache status is unclean and very little is stored there.  This is actually what I am trying to solve with selenium: do a clean shutdown after firefox operations. 

I can live with the /tmp directory as long as I can prevent it being deleted.

Comment: Not really. See my later post about this.

Comment: I have updated the question with additional information. It appears this one is unsolved in Python as only Java has the reap_profile functionality enabled.    A hack will fix this in my case, though, as I can easily modify selenium source. The setup will be temporary anyway in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Addition 5:34PM: Java API documentation mentions a system property webdriver.reap_profile that would prevent deletion of temporary files. I went to the source of the problem and it appears this does not appear in Python WebDriver class:

```
def quit(self):
        """Quits the driver and close every associated window."""
        try:
            RemoteWebDriver.quit(self)
        except (http_client.BadStatusLine, socket.error):
            # Happens if Firefox shutsdown before we've read the response from
            # the socket.
            pass
        self.binary.kill()
        try:
            shutil.rmtree(self.profile.path)
            if self.profile.tempfolder is not None:
                shutil.rmtree(self.profile.tempfolder)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
```

Deletion of files upon quit appears to be unconditional. I will solve this in my case by injecting

```
return self.profile.path
```

in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py just after self.binary.kill(). This probably breaks all sorts of things and is a horrible thing to do but it appears to do exactly what I want it to do. The return value tells the calling function the random name of the temporary directory under /tmp. Not elegant but appears to wor after a recompile.

If a more elegant solution exists, I would be happy to flag that as the correct one.